# Count Number of games per product type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I count `NumOfGames%` per product type like `% = TOTAL/PERPRODUT_TYPE`.
Here is my query for the `TOTAL NumOfGames`

```
 SELECT     
        DPT.[Name] [ProductType],
        SUM([FinishedGameCycleCount]) [NumOfGames]  
    FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[FactGameAgr] FWA
    JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimPlayer] DPL ON FWA.[PlayerId] = DPL.[Id]
    JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimGame] DG ON FWA.[GameId] = DG.[Id]
    JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimProductType] DPT ON DPT.Id = FWA.ProductTypeId
    WHERE  [WarehouseMgmt].[GetDateTimeFromTimeId](TimeId) >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)), 0)
    GROUP BY DPT.[Name]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUM() OVER()

```
SELECT     
        DPT.[Name] [ProductType],
        SUM([FinishedGameCycleCount]) [NumOfGames],
        SUM([FinishedGameCycleCount]) *100. / SUM(SUM([FinishedGameCycleCount])) OVER() [percentage]
    FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[FactGameAgr] FWA
    JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimPlayer] DPL ON FWA.[PlayerId] = DPL.[Id]
    JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimGame] DG ON FWA.[GameId] = DG.[Id]
    JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimProductType] DPT ON DPT.Id = FWA.ProductTypeId
    WHERE  [WarehouseMgmt].[GetDateTimeFromTimeId](TimeId) >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)), 0)
    GROUP BY DPT.[Name]
```